# Ruby - Grab Most Pairs From a Hash

Tags: ruby, hash

```
hsh = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: [1, 3, 1, 4] }
```

How do i grab all key/value pairs from the hash except for where the value is an array? Or, how do i grab all key/value pairs from the hash except for where the key is :four?

Comment: Look at Hash#reject: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-reject

Answer (score 4):

It is not clear what you mean by "grab". To get a hash, do the following:

```
hsh.reject{|k, v| v.kind_of?(Array)}
hsh.reject{|k, v| k == :four}
```

Comment: means `select`.. *grab* is no technical word.. :-)